# Glob for a set of file extensions everywhere except a single folder

Tags: glob

I need to write a glob to match various file types (`*.{js,ts,md,json,yaml,yml,css,html}`) everywhere inside my project directory and all its subdirectories, except for `ignored-folder`. For example:

```
should-match.js
src/should-match.ts
src/nested/should-match.css
ignored/should-NOT-match.json
```

This is pretty close:

```
!(ignored-folder)/**/*.{js,ts,md,json,yaml,yml,css,html}
```

However, it doesn't include the root-level `should-match.js`. Some way to fix it it is to basically duplicate the last segment like this:

```
{*.{js,ts,md,json,yaml,yml,css,html},!(ignored-folder)/**/*.{js,ts,md,json,yaml,yml,css,html}}
```

With variables, it could be written like this:

```
{$EXTENSIONS,!(ignored-folder)/**/$EXTENSIONS}
```

However, I can't use variables so the duplication is a bit unpleasant. Is there a better way to write the glob?

Comment: Would `{.,!(ignored-folder)}/**/*.{js,ts,md,json,yaml,yml,css,html}` work?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
{!(ignored-folder)/**/,}*.{js,ts,md,json,yaml,yml,css,html}
```